# Running three js without local server?

Tags: three.js, cefsharp

I am currently working with WPF project. My task is to display 3d models that generates in real-time with the help of CefSharp.

We already have the same project but in 2d. It only uses vanilla JS and svg. With 3d, I will be using threeJS. My problem is that, I cant just open the html file directly since it uses ESmodules and will be blocked by CORS.

My question is, Is it possible to disable CORS in CefSharp? I did the same with chrome and it worked. If not, how can I set up a local server in CefSharp that will execute in real time and will work with different clients? Thank you so much!

Comment: You don't need a web server, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#resource-handling (`FolderSchemeHandlerFactory` is the option I'd go for by default)

Comment: You could also use a build tool (like Webpack, for example) to combine all of your code so it can be inserted directly into your HTML. That will eliminate loading external resources.